# Keil: Assembler program that converts ASCII number into BCD and HEX

Tags: assembly, keil

this Keil uVision program should load a positive whole ASCII number (e.g 1234). The Program should convert it into BCD coded number in Register R1 , and the HEX number in Register 2...
can someone explain me what it does below?
especially :

```
MOV     R4,#10
```

and

```
AND     R1,R3,#0xF
MLA     R2,R4,R2,R3
```

???
here is the program:

```
LDR R0, =Wert ; Pointer laden
    LDR R1,[R0]
    BL KONVERT ; Unterprogramm KONVERT aufrufen
endlos         B        endlos


KONVERT
    LDRB    R3,[R0],#1 ; Byte laden
    AND     R1,R3,#0xF ; ASCII-HEX-Wandlung
    MOV     R2,R1 ; HEX-Zahl
    MOV     R4,#10

    LDRB    R3,[R0],#1 ; nächstes laden
    AND     R3,R3,#0xF ; ASCII-Hex-Wandlung
    ORR     R1,R3,R1,LSL #4 ; BCD-Wert bilden
    MLA     R2,R4,R2,R3 ; HEX-Zahl

    LDRB    R3,[R0],#1 ; nächstes laden
    AND     R3,R3,#0xF ; ASCII-Hex-Wandlung
    ORR     R1,R3,R1,LSL #4 ; BCD-Wert bilden
    MLA     R2,R4,R2,R3 ; HEX-Zahl

    LDRB    R3,[R0],#1 ; nächstes laden
    AND     R3,R3,#0xF ; ASCII-Hex-Wandlung
    ORR     R1,R3,R1,LSL #4 ; BCD-Wert bilden
    MLA     R2,R4,R2,R3 ; HEX-Zahl

    BX      LR ; Rücksprung
```

Comment: I't pretty well documented, so where is the problem?

Comment: If you don't understand German, http://translate.google.com/ can be useful.

Comment: MOV     R4,#10 is not documented , and thanks you are not helpful..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MOV     R4,#10
; loads constant 10 decimal into R4

AND     R1,R3,#0xF
; 0x0F & R3 are stored in R1 (AND operation). This is used to remove the 0x30 offset of the numbers 0-9 in ASCII

MLA     R2,R4,R2,R3
; (R2 * R4) + R3 are stored in R2 (Multiply-Accumulate operation)
```

The [ARM Infocenter](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0489c/Cihihggj.html) is a good starting point for such questions.

Comment: what use has it to load constant 10 into R4?

Comment: it's used to build the hex number (HEX-Zahl) in r2. E.g. you have a string like 1234 which is "one-thousand-two-hundred-thirty-four". You begin reading at the most significant digit, multiply it by 10 and add the next digit, multiply it by 10, and so on.

Comment: (((((1*10)+2)*10)+3)*10)+4=1234